# Is there a way to set the field of view (FOV) higher?

Tags: space-engineers

The game currently only lets you set a max FOV of 90 in the in-game settings. Is there a file in the game's directory I can edit to exceed this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize I'm responding to a really old question but this page comes up pretty quickly in Google.

You can definitely set the FOV higher than 90 as the game doesn't seem to check what is loaded from the config file. It's is located at `%APPDATA%\SpaceEngineers\SpaceEngineers.cfg`

Here's what I have in mine to set the FOV at 120:

```
<item>
  <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">FieldOfView</Key>
  <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">120</Value>
</item>
```